# How to use Google push notification services with ios app

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app already made and it supports push notification. I used Google cloud messaging for push notification. How to make the same push notification work on ios. 
Do I have to make another one using apple push notification services?

Answer (score 2):

Android and iOS are coded very differently, you can't just copy the app code in your android app and put it directly into an iOS app. You will have to learn how iOS push notifications work. I suggest this tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925

Comment: Ok thank you I just wanted to know if their is a way to not to do the whole work twice.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Push Notification in IOS device you need to integrate **Apple's APNS service**.
Follow this link:
 [Apple's APNS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: Ok thank you I just wanted to know if their is a way to not to do the whole work twice.